# How to redirect in jQuery using POST instead of GET

Tags: jquery

In my jQuery function I'm redirecting Using window.location.href like this:

```
window.location.href = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/redirectUser.ajax?login="+response.result.name;
```

It works fine, but I see this String in browser like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/task7/redirectUser.ajax?login=user
```

My controller also uses GET

```
@RequestMapping (value="/redirectUser.ajax",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String forwardUserToUsersPage(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest req){
        User foundedUser = userDao.findByLogin(req.getParameter("login"));
        req.getSession().setAttribute("user", foundedUser);
        return "userPage";//to WEB-INF/jsp/userPage.jsp
    }
```

How can I rewrite this part of application in order to user POST method to redirect and to handle in controller ?

Here is function that receives reply from servler (part of function actually)

```
function doAjaxPost() {
    // get the form values
    var queryString = $('#loginform').formSerialize();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "${pageContext. request. contextPath}/loginUser.ajax",
    data: queryString, 
        //"name=" + name + "&pswd=" + pswd,

    success: function(response){    
        // we have the response
        var delay = 1500;
        if (response.status == "OK_USER") {
            $('#error').html('');
            $('#info').html("Login exists, password is correct everything will be fine.<br> Redirect to User's page"); 

            //var delay = 3000;
            setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/redirectUser.ajax?login="+response.result.name;
            }, delay);

        } 
....
```

So how can I redirect using jQuery or something else using POST method ?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way I see :

create a `<form>` node, set its `action` to the correct URL and `method="post"`, fill it with the desired parameters (in `<input>` fields), and call `.submit()`.

e.g. :

```
...
setTimeout(function(){
    var $form = $('<form>').attr({
        action: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/redirectUser.ajax",
        method: "post"
    });

    $form.append('<input name="login" value="'+response.result.name'" />');
    $form.submit();
}, delay);
...
```

Comment: There is a form which is validated using jQuery validation plugin. This function gets answer from controller and then redirects user to userPage.jsp or to adminPage.jsp. 

I did this by using simple javascript window.location.href
Maybe there is the same function in jQuery ?

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work. 
I just get this string in my browser in page body:
{"status":"OK_USER","result":{"name":"user","pswd":"123"}}

I've changed controller to POST and added @ModelAttribute(value="login") String login,
Still doesn't work

Comment: In that case, you did not give the correct url to log a user in. If `redirectUser.ajax` is meant to be interrigated via `ajax` and return data formatted in `json`, you should use it as such. Look at your app's logic and check how a user should be authenticated.

Comment: As an added note, I would say it us pretty dangerous to have an ajax service which, when you provide a user's login, returns its password in plain text...